# Adding several JSONObject into one but not as an array

Tags: java, json

I am working on a java API and I need to format some data into JSON. I want the following structure :

```
{
   "main": {
            "point1": {
              "x": 0.18,
              "y": 10.8,
              "z": 0
            },
            "point2": {
              "x": 0.18,
              "y": 9.36,
              "z": 0
            },
            "point3": {
              "x": 0.18,
              "y": 8.46,
              "z": 0
            },
            "point4": {
              "x": 0.18,
              "y": 7.38,
              "z": 0
            }
    }
}
```

Basically there is a list of points in the "main" JSONObject object but I don't want it to be an array.

```
JSONObject main = new JSONObject();

for(Point p : points){
    JSONObject point = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject coordinates = new JSONObject();
    coordinates.put("x", p.getX());
    coordinates.put("y", p.getY());
    coordinates.put("z", p.getZ());
    point.put(p.getName(),coordinates);
    main.put("main", point);
}
```

I get the following result with the code above :

```
{
   "main": {
            "point4": {
              "x": 0.18,
              "y": 7.38,
              "z": 0
            }
    }
}
```

The put method I use on the last line is overwritting the previous points, so I only got one point in the main object at the end. I guess the solution to my problem is trivial but I'm unable to find it. 
Could you help me with that ?

Comment: *"but I don't want it to be an array"* Why not? What's wrong with that approach? Can you please add a [mcve] where we can test?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, I just need to follow specifications that were not made by me, so I don't have the choice

Comment: Note that it may sometimes be a good idea to challenge those specifications. Of course only you know if it would be appropriate in the context of your project, but there are multiple strategies depending on the context, i.e. directly going to the guy who wrote the specs when you receive them, or talking about it to your manager, or talking about it to anyone around a coffee after you've implemented the solution... Here a possible argument would be that the points all have the same meaning (no order or hierarchy between them) and that it doesn't make sense to "identify"/label them.

Comment: I agree with Aaron. I am completely unable to think of *a single* use case to not use an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there.

Accumulate all points into a single JSON object by adding each point as a separate field:

```
JSONObject main = new JSONObject();

List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
points.add(new Point("point1", 1, 2, 3));
points.add(new Point("point2", 2, 3, 4));

JSONObject pointsAsJson = new JSONObject();
for (Point p : points) {
    JSONObject coordinates = new JSONObject();
    coordinates.put("x", p.getX());
    coordinates.put("y", p.getY());
    coordinates.put("z", p.getZ());
    pointsAsJson.put(p.getName(), coordinates);
}

main.put("main", pointsAsJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the original `for` loop.

```
JSONObject main = new JSONObject();
for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
     JSONObject coordinates = new JSONObject();
     coordinates.put("x", points[i].getX());
     coordinates.put("y", points[i].getY());
     coordinates.put("z", points[i].getZ());
     main.put("point" + i, coordinates);
}
```

Comment: This code produces the example I added in the question, everytime you put something in "main" object  with the put method in the for loop, it overwrites the previous point and at the end you got only one point in the JSON